# android: 9 patch image with transparent borders as a part of the image

Tags: android, image, nine-patch

9-patch images should have transparent border where 9-patch markup is made:
http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html

But i have 9-patch image with 4 pixels more as a part of the image. I've marked them as not sizeable parts, but they are totally ignored and only not transparent pixels are displayed.

How can i mark transparent image pixels as an image part?

Answer (score 1):

Hi,

Try like this:

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imgButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/refresh_icon"
    android:background="@drawable/background_image">
```

Resources:

[refresh_icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4hgN.png)

[background_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/677bt.png)

Comment: i use it exactly in that way. But transparent pixls are recognized at 'markup area' and are not displayed at all.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using draw9patch in android sdk? I'm using draw9patch, when I make an image with photoshop including transparent pixels with amount of which I want, then the image opend with draw9patch, I can see the position of 9patch pixel is edge of the image which is outer position with transparent pixels.

Comment: yes, of coarse. i draw image with transparent borders in pain.NET. Then open it in using sdk tool and save it into ..9.png file